# Any hint for this measure theory problem?

Tags: measure-theory

I need a hint because I really don't know where to start:

Let $O \subset \Bbb R$ be open and let $f:O \to \Bbb R$ be a  $\mathcal{C}^1$ function. Show that if $A \subset O$ and $m(A)=0$ then $m(f(A))=0$.

Any hint or idea will be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: take $\{K_n\}$ a sequence of compact sets increasing to $O$, and define $A_n:=A\cap K_n$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $K_{n}$. For a fixed $\varepsilon>0$, there are disjoint intervals $I_i=(a_i,b_i)$ whose union covers $A\cap K_n$ the $\sum_ib_i-a_i\lt\varepsilon$. Then $\mu(f(A\cap K_n))\lt \varepsilon \cdot C_n$ ($C_n$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$ on $K_n$). We deduce that $\mu(f(A\cap K_n))=0$ for each $n$.